# extra margin from bottom of page in bottomsheetdialog

Tags: android, dialog, bottom-sheet

This is my class:

```java
public class RoundedBottomSheetDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    @Override
    public int getTheme () {
        return R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme;
    }

    @Override
    public BottomSheetDialog onCreateDialog (Bundle savedinstance) {
        BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(getActivity(), R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme);
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

why my bottomSheetDialog has some extra margin bottom of screen and not fitted to bottom of screen of display?

Answer (score 0):

MY Problem was this line:
getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);